# JavaScript flatMap() method logging NaN when action is performed on element

Tags: javascript, arrays

Alright, this is a very basic question, but I'm not seeing the fix here. I want to flatten an array that has one layer of depth and at the same time multiply each element by 2. However, when I run flat map on arr1 the console is returning NaN instead of an array of 5 elements with each element being multiplied by 2. Code example below:

const arr1 = [ [2,5] , [5,10,15] ];

const arr2 = arr1.flatMap((el) => el * 2);

console.log(arr2);

Expected // [4, 10, 10, 20, 30]

Actual // [Nan, Nan]

If I run the flatMap without the multiplication I get the array with each element but it's only once I try to mulitply each value that I get the two NaN. What am I missing?

const arr3 = arr1.flatMap((el) => el);
console.log(arr3);

Actaul // [2,5,5,10,15];

Comment: `[2,5]` is an Array so `[2,5] * 2` is `NaN` - i think you've misunderstood what flatMap does - it's equivalent of `map` then `flat`, not `flat` then `map` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) - so you want `arr1.flat(Infinity).map(el => el*2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `el` within your `.flatMap()` callback represents each of your elements in your array, which in your case will firstly be `[2,5]` and then on the next iteration will be `[5,10,15]`. Trying to multiply an array using `el*2` will give you back `NaN`. Instead, what `.flatMap()` does is if you return an array from the callback, it will take all the elements from within that array and join it into the final resulting array. With this in mind, you can make your callback return an array of mapped/multiplied numbers, which then are all joined together in a final resulting array by `.flatMap()`:

```js
const arr1 = [ [2,5] , [5,10,15] ];
const arr2 = arr1.flatMap(inner => inner.map(el => el* 2));
console.log(arr2); // [4, 10, 10, 20, 30]
```

Comment: This makes sense, I was a little confused by the syntax of flatMap and thought you could just use a single method to achieve the above result of arr2. TY!

Answer (score -1):

```js
const arr1 = [ [2,5] , [5,10,15] ];

var flattened = arr1.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
});
console.log(flattened)
const arr2 = flattened.flatMap((el) => el * 2);
console.log(arr2)
```

If you have nested array then you have to first flatten it then apply flatMap.Please read about how [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) works.

Comment: This isn't the correct way to use `.flatMap()`. You would get the same result if you were to call `.map()`